# Показать максимум элементов, которые поместятся

Tags: css

Добрый день!

Есть контейнер с шириной 100%. Хочется в этом контейнере показать столько ссылок, сколько туда поместится без переноса на другую сточку. Т.к. ширина контейнера неизвестна, хочется разместить туда все ссылки которые у меня есть, но скрыть те, которые в контейнер не влезают полностью. То есть избежать ситуации, когда ссылки будут обрезаны. Что бы избежать ситуации как:

Похожие статьи - как готовить капусту, как готовить кабачки, как готовить говя

Если ссылка с говядиной не влезает, то и не показывать ее, а не обрезать.

Можно ли это как-то реализовать на css?

Спасибо

Comment: добавьте пример своего кода в котором обрезается

Comment: как вариант  - текст обрезается и к концу строки добавиться многоточие - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ynsdpv1z/

Answer (score 3):

```js
content = document.querySelector('.content');
button = document.querySelectorAll('button');
button[0].onclick = function() {content.style = 'width: 430px';};
button[1].onclick = function() {content.style = 'width: 600px';};
```

```css
.content {
  width: 600px;
  background: #F0F4F8;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

span a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #61aceb;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <span>Похожие статьи: </span>
  <span><a href='#'>как готовить капусту</a>,</span>
  <span><a href='#'>как готовить кабачки</a>,</span>
  <span><a href='#'>как готовить говядину</a></span>
</div>

<button>430 px</button>
<button>600 px</button>
```

Или по предоставленному примеру из комментария

Ключевую роль играет `overflow: hidden` и `height: 16px` в основном блоке и заданный параметр `display: inline-block` у ссылки

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F0F4F8;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 64px;
}

div a {
  margin-left: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
}

div a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #2c86d2;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#">как готовить капусту</a>
    <a href="#">как готовить кабачки</a>
    <a href="#">как готовить какахи</a>
    <a href="#">как готовить блины</a>
    <a href="#">как готовить плов</a>
    <a href="#">как готовить сырники</a>
    <a href="#">как готовить осьминога</a>
    <a href="#">как готовить Grundy</a>
    <a href="#">как готовить кексики</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот спасибо! Про   overflow: hidden; я понимаю, а зачем явно задавать height: 16px?

Comment: @anacol, если убрать `hidden` то будет видно куда уходит текст, который не влез. А высота в `16px` равна высоте одной строчке

Comment: а почему высота одной строчки равна именно 16-ти?

Comment: @anacol, если у `div a` будет `font-size: 24px`, то и высоту блока придётся подстроить под 24px. По умолчанию размер шрифта задан в 16px. Или подстраиваться под `line-height`